# How do I render ForeignKey fields in my template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm making a comment system for my django app and i've been told it's best to make a seperate model for comment-voting. So i've done that and here's my **models.py**:

```
    class Comment(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
        destination = models.CharField(default='1', max_length=12, blank=True)
        author = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
        comment_id = models.IntegerField(default=1)
        parent_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        comment_text = models.TextField(max_length=350, blank=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.comment_text


    class CommentScore(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
        comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='score')
        upvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        downvotes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.comment)
```

Here's my **views.py** where the comments are created:

```
def article(request, category, id):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        if b == name:
            name = a
            instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)


    #comments
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
    ajax_comment = request.POST.get('text')
    comment_length = len(str(ajax_comment))

    #database_comment = get_object_or_404(Comments, comment_id=1)
    comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
    score = CommentScore.objects.filter(comment=comment_list)

    if request.is_ajax():
        if comment.is_valid():
            comment = Comment.objects.create(comment_text=ajax_comment, author=str(request.user), destination=id)
            print(comment)
            comment.save()

            score = CommentScore.objects.create(comment=comment)
            score.save()
            username = str(request.user)
            return JsonResponse({'text': ajax_comment, 'text_length': comment_length, 'username': username})
        else:
            print(comment.errors)

    context = {
        'score': score,
        'comment_list': comment_list,
        'comment': comment,
        'instance': instance,
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup
    }

    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

So the `comment` works fine, but as you can see a couple lines later i'm trying to then create a `CommentScore` instance to match with the `comment`. In my template, I've rendered each comment and it's fields (`comment_text`, `author` etc), but I want to render the `upvotes` field associated with that `comment`. How would I do this?

**template**

```
{% for i in comment_list %}
    <div class='comment_div'>
        <h3>{{ i.author }}</h3>
        <p>{{ i.comment_text }}</p><br>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

**forms.py**

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment

        fields = [
            'comment_text',
            'id',
            'author',
            'destination',
        ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your view you have this line:

```
comment_list = Comment.objects.filter(destination=id)
```

so if you want to get to `CommentScore` that associated with `Comment`, you have to write like this on your view:

```
score = CommentScore.objects.filter(comment=comment_list)
```

`filter` expects multiple variable so you can access to `upvotes` in your template, like this:

```
{% for i in score %}    
   {{i.upvotes}}
{% endfor %}
```

if you have single `score` instance, you have to use `get` parameter:

score = CommentScore.objects.get(comment=comment_list)

then you can you just

```
 {{score.upvotes}}
```

on your template

Comment: Is `{{ commentscore.upvotes }}` supposed to go in my template `{% for %}` loop? Because I did that and it's not returning anything.

Comment: Added full view and forms.py

Comment: I've copied your code and `{% for i in score %}    
   {{i.upvotes}}
{% endfor %}` still doesn't render anything

Comment: Wait I think it's working now when I make new comments..thanks for the help.

Comment: My congratulations! Mark question as answered!